# Should I include the source for a testing framework in my application's repository?

Tags: testing, configuration, repository

Is it normal to include the source for a testing framework in the tested application's repository.

For example, a C++ application tested with googletest. Does googletest code go in my repo? If so how do I handle building. Do I have my makefile call googletest's makefile?

Alternatively, should I ask the end user to provide an environment variable pointing to googletest if they want to run the tests?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this. This is not a good fit for this site as it stands; it's asking for opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically all your tests will be in a separate repository, I know for us we have all of our integration tests in a different repository but keep unit tests local.

Do you really want your clients to see all your test cases? Do the tests really need to be run on client machines? These are questions you have to ask yourself. Then you will have your answer